# How to make react-modal scrollable?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-modal

Im trying to make my modal (react-modal node package) scrollable (There is an img inside)

here is my code:

```
  content: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    padding: '15px',
    zIndex: '1000',
    width: '90%',
    borderRadius: '.5em',
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'fixed',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .8)',
    zIndex: '1000',
    overflowY: 'auto',
  },
}

Modal.setAppElement('#__next')

export const langContext = React.createContext()

export default function Home() {
  const [isEn, setIsEn] = useState(true)
  const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions()

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true)
  }

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  function updateLang() {
    setIsEn((isEn) => !isEn)
  }
  return (
    <langContext.Provider value={{ isEn, updateLang }}>
      <div id="modal" className="overflow-hidden relative">
        <Header />
        <Modal
          isOpen={modalIsOpen}
          onRequestClose={closeModal}
          style={customStyles}>
          <div className="relative m-h-[1000px] h-full w-full overflow-y-scroll">
            {isEn ? (
              <Image
                layout="fill"
                objectFit={width >= 750 ? 'fill' : ' cover'}
                quality={100}
                src={
                  width >= 750 ? '/assets/menu-en.png' : '/assets/Menu_en_m.png'
                }
                alt="Menu"
              />
            ) : (
              <Image
                layout="fill"
                objectFit={width >= 750 ? 'fill' : ' cover'}
                quality={100}
                src={
                  width >= 750 ? '/assets/menu-he.png' : '/assets/Menu_he_m.png'
                }
                alt="Menu"
              />
            )}
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </langContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Any ideas on how can I do it? (I'm trying to play with the overflow and position element but I can't find the proper solution

The scrolling suppose to happen on Mobile and the Image dimensions are: 550*1550 (I can resize it if necessary)
Right now the image is cut

Thanks for the helpers!

[image]

Comment: Could you share your `Modal` styles? that would help to find where you're struggling

Comment: Hi. all the styling is in the code snippet. Id dint add any more styles elsewhere

Comment: Could you screenshot your modal right now? Do you want to have an inner scroller or an outer scroller for that modal?

Comment: Hi, I added a picture of how it looks on mobile. I guess an inner scrollbar would be the best but I don't really care as long it will work =)

Comment: this comment section is not enough for the explanation, so I put it in the answer section instead

Answer (score 0):

I think your modal is good in terms of vertical scrolling, but the problem has may come from this line

```
objectFit={width >= 750 ? 'fill' : 'cover'}
```

Your mobile dimension is 500*1550 which means the image will take `object-fit:cover;`

You can check `object-fit:cover;` definition [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

> The image keeps its aspect ratio and fills the given dimension. The image will be clipped to fit

If you already check the dimension to load the device-respective image, you can remove the condition to check for `cover`.

`object-fit:fill` is sufficient for your case

The change can be

```
objectFit="fill"
```

Another potential problem I can see here that you have `layout="fill"` for that image which will make it `absolute`. The image container has `relative` which restricts the original size of your image.

To fix it, you may need to remove `relative` from the image container too.

Comment: Actually, i tried to play with those parameters and it didn't work...

Comment: You also need to remove `relative` on the image container (the parent element of that image) to lift the barrier for the image size because `layout="fill"` will make image `absolute` @NavehMevorach

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks